# accepts_nested_attributes_for and new records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm using accepts_nested_attributes_for with the following models:

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :competences
  has_many :skills, :through => :competences, :foreign_key => :skill_id

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills
end
```

Skill model:

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :competences
  has_many :users, :through => :competences, :foreign_key => :user_id
end
```

Competence model:

```
class Competence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

The Skill table has a "name" attribute. How can I have accepts_nested_attributes_for not create a new skill record if a record with the same skill name already exists?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I have the exact same setup with a `validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true` on the Skill.  When entering a skill with the same name in the nested attributes form I get a uniqueness validation error.  I'd like to be able to use the existing Skill if the name matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid creating a new skill by validating the skill name to be unique:

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

I guess what you really want to know though, is how to associate the existing skill with the name they have specified to the new user instead of creating a new skill when one already exists.

If you are trying to do that it suggests to me that the attributes shouldn't actually be nested at all.

You could probably do it with a `before_save` callback if you really wanted to but again, it kind of defeats the purpose of nested attributes:

```
class User << ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :check_for_existing_skill
  def check_for_existing_skill
    if self.skill
      existing_skill = Skill.find_by_name(self.skill.name)
      if existing_skill
        self.skill = existing_skill
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried this recently and I cannot get this to work. Is this method of doing this still possible? What would be the correct way of doing this without using the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is answered here: [accepts_nested_attributes_for with find_or_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579924/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-find-or-create/)