# Rails nested form on many-to-many: how to prevent duplicates?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, many-to-many, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I've setup a nested form in my rails 3.2.3 app, it's working fine, my models are:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description, :excerpt, :date, :ingredient_lines_attributes

  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredient_lines
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient_lines
end
```

and:

```
class IngredientLine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :ingredient_id, :measurement_unit_id, :quantity

  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipes
  belongs_to :measurement_unit
  belongs_to :ingredient
end
```

As above, a Recipe can have multiple IngredientLines and vice versa.

What I'm trying to avoid is record duplication on IngredienLine table.

For example imagine that for recipe_1 an IngredientLine with {"measurement_unit_id" => 1, "ingredient_id" => 1, "quantity" => 3.5} is associated, if for recipe_5 the IngredientLine child form is compiled by the user with the same values, I don't want a new record on IngredientLine table, but only a new association record in the join table ingredient_lines_recipes.

Note that currently I dont't have any IngredientLine controller as saving and updating IngredientLines is handled by nested form routines. Even my Recipe controller is plain and standard:

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
  end

  def create
    @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])
    flash[:notice] = 'Recipe saved.' if @recipe.save  
    respond_with(@recipe)
  end

  def destroy
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @recipe.destroy
    respond_with(:recipes)
  end

  def edit
    respond_with(@recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id]))
  end

  def update
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    flash[:notice] = 'Recipe updated.' if @recipe.update_attributes(params[:recipe])
    respond_with(@recipe)
  end

end
```

My guess is that should be enough to override the standard `create` behavior for IngredientLine with `find_or_create`, but I don't know how to achieve it.

But there's another important point to take care, imagine the edit of a child form where some IngredientLines are present, if I add another IngredientLine, which is already stored in IngredientLine table, rails of course should not write anything on IngredientLine table, but should also distinguish between child records already associated to the parent, and the new child record for which needs to create the relation, writing a new record on the join table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

in Recipe model redefine method

```
def ingredient_lines_attributes=(attributes)
   self.ingredient_lines << IngredientLine.where(attributes).first_or_initialize
end
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but can't destroy children once created, association also duplicates every time the parent is saved.

I'm getting closer overriding `assign_nested_attributes_for_collection_association(association_name, attributes_collection, assignment_opts = {})` but the problem seems to be that `association.build` always want to save the record, while `association.add_to_target` doesn't add the fetched object, don't know why.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8510a0bb5a8a65e4bc067ee5a7d98aae965b47a5/activerecord/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb#L371

Comment: so then the only option is to remove accepts_nested_att..., and write your own getter and setter, and in setter u have to check if self.new_record? then ...

Comment: Well I suppose.. but not an elegant solution at all since you can't leverage the nested form code from rails core.
I came to conclusion that this issue is directly related with the inability or rails in correctly handling the many-to-many relation which is also a consequence of not allowing composite primary keys.
If I try to insert and relate a record in a many-to-many, the framework should check if the record exists and if so, only create the relation with a record in the join table.
This is not possible because a generic ID pk usually is not a good choice to represent the unique constraint

Answer (score 2):

Old question but I had the same problem. Forgot to add :id to white list with rails 4 strong_parameters.

For example:

widgets_controller.rb

```
def widget_params
  params.require(:widget).permit(:name, :foos_attributes => [:id, :name, :_destroy],)
end
```

widget.rb

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :foos, allow_destroy: true
end
```

foo.rb

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :widget
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into a similar situation and found inspiration in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3580267/5610). In short, I don't worry about the duplication of nested models until save time.

Translated to your example, I added `autosave_associated_records_for_ingredient_lines` to `Recipe`. It iterates through `ingredient_lines` and performs a `find_or_create` as your intuition said. If ingredient_lines are complex, Yuri's `first_or_initialize` approach may be cleaner.

I believe this has the behavior you're looking for: nested models are never duplicated, but editing one causes a new record rather than updating a shared one. There is the strong possibility of orphaned `ingredient_lines` but if that's a serious concern you could choose to update if that model has only one `recipe` with an id that matches the current one.