# update not propagated in nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a nested models set :

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :place
      :place
    attr_accessible :place_attributes, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => false

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :events
    validates :label, :presence => true, 
        :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => true, :on => :create }
    validates :description, :presence => {:on => :create}, 
        :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => true , :on => :create}
```

In a test scenario, w the nested form, the user can update only the Place#label attributes, keeping all the other information..

```
test "should_update_event_place_data" do
    put :update, :locale => I18n.locale, :id => @event[:id],
      :event => { :place_attributes => { label: "a very beautiful place" } }
```

which leads to a request to EventsController#update, receiving the parameters :

```
params
    {"event"=>{"place_attributes"=>{"label"=>"a very beautiful place"}}, "locale"=>"en",
    "id"=>"145", "controller"=>"backoffice/events", "action"=>"update"}

(rdb:1)  @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
 false
@messages={:"place.description"=>["cannot be blank"]
```

But the validation is on create , not update .... no validation error should be detected ..
what could be wrong ?

thanks for help

```
I did more testing 
debugger , right after the test setup ( before sending the put request)
@event_0
#<Event id: 161, account_id: 3, place_id: 249, slug: "my-new-event-on-2013-01-01-at-    edinburgh-united-king...", title: "My New Event"
 @event_0.place
#<Place id: 249, label: "new fake place",..

test request:
put :update, :locale => I18n.locale, :id => @event_0[:id], :event => { :place_attributes => {  label: "a very beautiful place"} }

params in request are OK, @request/method = PUT

In EventsController#update
@event.update_attributes(params[:event])
.... I inserted a debug in the Place model... 
(before_validation :i_am_on_create, :on => :create)
  def i_am_on_create
    debugger
    p "CREATING"
  end

 and it's creating !! don't understand why it's not updating the parent nested model
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code for the test and corresponding controller code?

Comment: Are you sure that the associated `description` already exists? It's impossible to tell without seeing your controller code, but it looks to me like although `@event` already exists, `@event.description` is being created and hence triggering validation when you update the parent event record. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update_attributes does not propagate the updates to associations. If you watch the source code (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) you'll see that the #save
is called in the end. And this is the default behaviour:

```
# existing resource 'mazeratti car' 
car.name = "Wheelz"
car.brand.label = "Ferrari"
car.save
car.reload
car.name #=> "Wheelz"
car.brand.label #=> "Mazeratti"
```

if you want associations to be updated all the time the object is updated, look into using "autosave" (http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to : Options)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting to test that the label attribute is updated, why not try doing update_attribute on that field only rather than the whole 'event'? Something like:

```
@event.place_attributes.update_attribute(
      :label => params[:event][:place_attributes][:label]
)
```

Not tested - but you get the idea...

Comment: thanks for the tip , I tested :
  place.update_attributes(:label => params[:event][:place_attributes][:label])
 and got the same issue with validation
@messages={:description=>["cannot be blank"]}

weird ..   validating presence of :description should not happen..
so it's not related with nested models.. but rather with validation options

Comment: I believe 'update_attributes' triggers the whole model validation, whereas 'update attribute' (as in my answer) does not. I notice in your comment above you're doing the plural: 'update_attributes'

Comment: As an aside, it you're using update_attributes you need to put some extra curly braces in to deal with multiple attributes: t.update_attributes({:a => 1, :b => 2})

Comment: `update_attribute` does not trigger any validation at all: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-validations

Comment: did more testing ... as a matter of fact , the nested models are not 'updated' but created again ...

Comment: I don't believe that's how it should behave. Have you got a 'before(:each)' statement in your test file that sets up the @event object (including the nested place_attributes) that we can see?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

in order to update the nested model, I need to add the model instance id :

```
 put :update, :locale => I18n.locale, :id => @event_0[:id], :event => { :place_attributes => { id: @event_0.place[:id],  label: "a very beautiful place"} }
```

so in :place_attributes , I added the existing @event_0.place[:id] , and it's now updating

I found it in Anson answer on Feb 17 at 17:04 bottom page at
[accepts_nested_attributes_for with find_or_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579924/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-find-or-create/)