# Rails 5: autosave associated record creating duplicate records of the parent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes, model-associations, cocoon-gem

I am currently learning rails and is attempting to create a Survey management application. The application have the following models:

```
class Survey < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_questions
  has_many :questions, through: : survey_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class SurveyQuestion < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :survey
  belongs_to :question
end

class Question < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :survey_questions
  has_many :surveys, through: :survey_questions
end
```

I want to be able to automatically associate existing questions ID to be used instead of creating a whole new list of questions every time I create a new Survey.

I found this solution which was close to what I want [accepts_nested_attributes_for with find_or_create?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579924/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-find-or-create) . It is able to associate my records correctly, but at the end of the transaction it will always create a new record at Question model regardless.

Can anyone suggest why is this happening and help point me to the right direction? Thank you!

**EDIT**

Below is the code for my `create`, `new` and `survey_params` method:

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  @questions = Question.all

  unless @question.blank?
    @questions.each do |question|
      @survey.questions.build(name: question)
    end
  end
end

def create
  @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)
  @survey.save!
end

def survey_params
  params.require(:survey).permit(:enddate, questions_params: [:name])
end
```

Below is my view for `new` and `questions_fields`, I am using cocoon gem to help me to help generate them dynamically:

new

```
= simple_form_for @survey, url: survey_index_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.input :finaldate, as: :string

  = f.simple_fields_for :questions do |qn|
    = render 'question_fields', f: qn

  = link_to_add_association 'New Question', f, :questions
```

question_fields

```
= f.input :name
= link_to_remove_association 'Remove Question', f
```

Comment: Can you include your controller `create` method in your question?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn done!

Comment: Great, one last question, could youi please include the form (view)?

Comment: I can tell you now there are a cvouple of problems evident... you shouldn't be using the "build" in edit as that is creating new records, not retrieving esisting records, and you'll need to pass the `:id` of the survey_questions back or you'll be creating new records for sure.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Sorry if I misunderstood you, but this isn't the edit method?

Comment: Ah, right, good point, sorry!  What does the edit method look like?

Comment: It's okay! I don't have an edit method